How can I reduce openliberty thread pool number
I have about 40 war application start together. By jstack, there are about more than 2000 thread in running. It's too much.
I want to know how can I reduce the number of thread pool? And there is a way to reduce start memory consumption and improve the start up time?

There are many different type of thread pool, such as pool-38-thread-42" Id=1493 and Default Executor-thread-55. What they do and where to execute them?

Why do you think that is too much? Different threads do different things and a thread dump would be needed to explain what they are doing, but thread count alone isn't something I'd recommend caring about. Typically when people ask about thread count there is another issue they actually have.

I am guessing that these are SpringBoot war applications possibly?  SpringBoot itself has multiple thread pools for each application.  The Liberty thread pool threads are the Default Executor-thread's.  If there are ways to tune the SpringBoot thread pools that will likely give you the reduction that you are looking for.  The liberty thread pool will automatically grow and shrink depending on load.

How would we know if we don't have any details? Even if you provide reproduction details asking about 40 apps is too broad in one question.

The 40 applications in your configuration may be contending for common resources during startup, making start slower.
You may be able to relieve this congestion by using the "startAfterRef" configuration in server.xml as described in this doc. Liberty Web Application Configuration
For example, you could define eight groups of five apps each, and daisy-chain the startup of the groups (group-2 starts after group-1, group-3 starts after group-2, etc) so that there are at most eight apps starting at one time.
